# Is there a way to do the sum of the n integers function that would have O(n^2)?

Tags: big-o

I want to write this simple function in a way that makes the big O notation of it O(n^2), how can I make that possible ?

```
int getSum(int n){ 
int sum = (n*(n+1))/2; 
return sum;
```

any ideas?

Comment: ....Repeat the calculation n² times?

Comment: The naïve solution is O(N).   You would need to be deliberately complicated to make it O(N^2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you want this, but you could do it with two nested loops:

```
int getSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int x = 0;
        while(x++ < i) {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This runs `1+2+3+...+n` times, which simplifies to `(n^2+n)/2`, hence `O(n^2)`

Comment: it's a homework that is worth 10% of my final grade, thank you so much, i thought of nested loops but couldn't figure how exactly i could do it.